# Is there any way I can see samples from libraries' source code?

Tags: android, composable

There is that `@sample` thing in docstrings from source code, like `@sample androidx.compose.foundation.samples.PlaceholderBasicTextFieldSample`. I was wondering how can I — if there is a way — see them, see this `PlaceholderBasicTextFieldSample`. Was trying to search for this, but had no luck.

Comment: Think these samples are documented here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main/docs/api_guidelines.md#enforcement but they don't work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just global search Github and it should lead you to a mirror of their repo.

[Androidx Repository](https://github.com/androidx/androidx)

Comment: Minor clarification... this is a mirror of their repo, the official repo is listed in the readme on the reference repo. It exists at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support. They don't use GitHub for source management. Possibly because they have over 2,000 separate repos that make up the Android source.

Comment: @SamuelNeff Cool! I didn't know that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

They work in d.android.com inline with the classes

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/package-summary#BasicTextField(kotlin.String,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardActions,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Int,androidx.compose.ui.text.input.VisualTransformation,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Brush,kotlin.Function1)